# A event YUI , every two seconds

Tags: jquery, yui

I want to create an event with YUI where every two seconds, refresh the page.

```
var companymain = {
init: function() {
  companymain.form = document.getElementById('companymain');
  //I need a event or something and repet this function.
  YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(companymain.form, 'EVENTNEED', companymain.submit_func);},

  submit_func: function(e) { //stuff refresh page}
```

ideas?
Regards.

Comment: I suspect you want `setTimeout()` - do a search around that, and you'll have a solution `:)`.

Comment: the thing is YUI works with function,callback and error. I dont know if it is possible use setTimeout.

Comment: Err, well... try it? `:)` (Make it easy on your readers, get a _jsFiddle_ on the go!)

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "create an event"? Because if you want something to happen every two seconds that's not really an event thing, it's a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` thing. When you say "refresh the page", do you mean "update part of it via Ajax" or "completely reload the whole page" (because the latter would also restart your JS)?

Comment: yeah. update part of it via Ajax. using setTimeout(). how will it be? 
t=setTimeout("submit_func()",1000);  doesnt work.

Comment: That doesn't work because there is no function called `submit_func()` - what there is is a property of the `companymain` object, `companymain.submit_func()`. See the last part of my answer below...

Comment: yeah. Your right. The solution was with jquery. thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want to do isn't really an event sort of thing. The following shows the general idea that you need to implement:

```
function repeatedRefresh(delay) {
   // Ajax code goes here

   setTimeout(repeatedRefresh, 2000);
}    
setTimeout(repeatedRefresh, 2000);
```

This declares a `repeatedRefresh()` function and calls it after 2000ms. The function itself will do an Ajax call to update the page and then use `setTimeout()` to queue up another call to itself after 2000ms. I'd suggest putting the `setTimeout()` inside the Ajax completion/success callback so that subsequent calls happen 2000ms after the previous one completes.

I've left the actual Ajax code out above because I'm not familiar with YUI (except in a very general way), but since you've tagged your question with jQuery this is one way to do it with jQuery:

```
function repeatedRefresh(delay) {
   $.ajax({
      url : "yourURLhere",
      data : "optionalDataHere",
      // other ajax params here as needed,
      success : function(result) {
         // do something with result (display it on your page somehow),
         // then queue up the next refresh
         setTimeout(repeatedRefresh, 2000);
      }
   });       
}    
setTimeout(repeatedRefresh, 2000);
```

Or if your server-side code is returning HTML you can simplify things by using the [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to automatically load the returned HTML into a particular element (say a div):

```
function repeatedRefresh() {
   $('#elementToUpdate').load('yourURLhere', function() {
      setTimeout(repeatedRefresh, 2000);
   });
}
setTimeout(repeatedRefresh, 2000);
```

Finally, to try to use your existing `companymain` structure:

```
var companymain = {
   init: function() {
      setTimeout(companymain.submit_func, 2000);
   },
   submit_func : function() {
      // YUI or jQuery (or other) Ajax code here

      setTimeout(companymain.submit_func, 2000);
   }
};    
companymain.init();
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed "YAHOO.util.Event.addListener" to setTimeout(companymain.submit_func, 2000). Since I saw that  YUI dont have a Event Time, your answer was great.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with setTimeout of course but YUI 2 has YAHOO.lang.later (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.lang.html#method_later) and YUI 3 has YUI.later (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_later) Both have the option to call a function periodically instead of once (so no need to define the hard coded delay twice in your code ;) )